# vim encode text to html and hex (for javascript)

Tags: vim, encoding

Is there any easy way to encode accents and special characters to html or hex ones? With Vim.

original text

> áh híhí

to html:

> &aacute ;h h&iacute ;h&iacute ;

to hex:

> \xE1h h\xEDh\xED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For HTML encoding it depends on how thorough you want to be.  One way to do it is to use the Perl module `HTML::Entities`.  It's thorough and fast, but rather heavy:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>h :silent %!perl -CIO -MHTML::Entities -pe '$_=encode_entities $_'<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>h :<C-u>silent '<,'>!perl -CIO -MHTML::Entities -pe '$_=encode_entities $_'<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>H :silent %!perl -CI  -MHTML::Entities -pe '$_=decode_entities $_'<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>H :<C-u>silent '<,'>!perl -CI  -MHTML::Entities -pe '$_=decode_entities $_'<CR>
```

The former two maps encode HTML entities, the latter ones decode them.  They apply to either the entire file, or to a range of marked lines.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to covert those non-ascii chars into HEX value:

```
%s/[^\x00-\x7f]/\=printf('\x%x',char2nr(submatch(0)))/g
```

with your line as example, the command changes it into:

```
\xe1h h\xedh\xed
```

Answer (score 1):

It is way too long to post here -- essentially a neverending series of substitutions -- and could probably be smarter but [my very first vimscript function](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim/blob/master/bundle/lang-html/autoload/html.vim#L33) is good at what it does: substituting regular characters with their corresponding HTML entities.

Scroll down for another function that does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

In visual mode, the substitution is always extended to the entire line. To solve this problem, I used:

```
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>h c<C-R>=system("perl -MHTML::Entities -p -e 'encode_entities($_)'", getreg('"'))<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>H c<C-R>=system("perl -MHTML::Entities -p -e 'decode_entities($_)'", getreg('"'))<CR>
```

or using the AstroNvim format, in `mappings.lua`:

```
 v = {
    ["<Leader>h"] = {
      "c<C-R>=system(\"perl -MHTML::Entities -p -e 'encode_entities($_)'\", getreg('\"'))<CR>",
      desc = "Encode XML/HTML Special Characters",
    },
    ["<Leader>H"] = {
      "c<C-R>=system(\"perl -MHTML::Entities -p -e 'decode_entities($_)'\", getreg('\"'))<CR>",
      desc = "Decode XML/HTML Special Characters",
    },
  },
```

So you can select (`vit`) and encode/decode, only the tag content.

*Disclaimer: I've been using vim since a couple of week*